# How to use Response.BeginFlush and Response.EndFlush for Asynchronous Pages

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, async-await

I'm using ASP.NET WebForms. In my PageLoad method, I register a task:

```
// c# code
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(BindAsync));
// more C# code here
```

Is it possible to flush the page while that task is running? From reading the [What's new in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097375), I understand Response.BeginFlush and Response.EndFlush should be able to do it, but I can't find any docs with usage or practical examples.

Any pointers or basic examples are appreciated.